# zoho mail rest api POST

Tags: php, api, email, curl, zoho

Here is the trouble. I have I cant seen to get it right. Any time I try to send a post to the api call.
https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/api/put-verify-domain.html
if shot me a error of JSON_PARSE_ERROR.
here is the body of the curl

```
[{"mode":"verifyDomainByCName"}]
```

```
curl header "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken $token", 'Content-Type: text/plain'
```

If I try this
{"mode":"verifyDomainByCName"}
I get a HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type

the base setting for curl

```
 curl_setopt_array ( $this->handler , [
                    CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $this->header,
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
                    CURLOPT_POST => true,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $this->data,
```

Thank you for any help
Karl K

Tried to run a script with a json body and keep getting error

Comment: The first would be incorrect, because it's looking for a single JSON object, not an array of objects. I don't see anything in their documentation about Unsupported Media Type

Comment: @aynber libcurl's default content-type when CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is non-empty is `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` , which is completely wrong if the body is a JSON, and the correct response if your web server expect a `Content-Type: application/JSON` but receives a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `Content-Type: text/plain`  is `HTTP 415: Unsupported Media Type`